# Expect: answering one or two ssh password prompts then interact

Tags: ssh, passwords, expect

I have an ssh case (can't use sshkeys) that sometimes prompts for one password, sometimes for two (prompt is the same in both cases).  I have tried variations of while, if, exp_continue, but can't seem to cook it correctly.

This works perfect if I only get one prompt:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set pwd "mypwd"
set prompt "*Password*"
set uid "*userid*"
set timeout -1
spawn -noecho ssh -q host.domain

expect $prompt
send $pwd
send \r
interact
```

Tried this, but not giving giving me the results I need for sometimes two pwds plus the KnownHost case.

```
expect {
    "*yes/no*" { send \"yes\r\"; exp_continue }
    $prompt { send \"$pwd\r\"; exp_continue }
    $uid {interact}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set pwd "mypwd"
set prompt "Enter PIN for 'PIV_II (PIV Card Holder pin)': "
set uid "*userid*"
set timeout -1
spawn ssh -q host.domain

expect {
    "*yes/no*" { send "yes\r"; exp_continue }
    $prompt { send "$pwd\r"; exp_continue }
    $uid { send \r; interact }
}
```

Comment: yes, need to be a bit careful about quoting, but not *too* careful